# SSRS linked reports

Tags: reporting-services

Is there any way that we can programmatically create linked reports in SSRS. I know the way to create a linked report in ReportManager by clicking on Create Linked Report button, but there is a requirement to do it programmatically and not manually.

Any Advice would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can look into RSScripter. http://sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62 
It creates .rs files which are basically vb scripts.  You can write up one for your
linked report and also add that linked report into the .cmd files to execute the rs file to deploy your linked report on your server.

Comment: Link is broken.